# rename columns with loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to rename columns in a df with a for-loop.

**Where am I going wrong with below?**

```
for col_name in df:
    df.rename(columns={col_name:col_name + '_x'})
```

**df now:**

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| - | - | - |

**Desired result:**

| Ax | Bx | Cx |
| --- | --- | --- |
| - | - | - |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with [**`columns`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) :

```
df.columns = [col + "x" for col in df.columns]
```

Or simply :

```
df.columns += "x"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Second one seems so obvious. 
Don't know why I was so stuck on needing a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **`inplace=True`** parameter:

```py
for col_name in df:
    df.rename(columns={col_name: col_name + "_x"}, inplace=True)
```

Prints:

```
  A_x B_x C_x
0   -   -   -
```

---

I recommend to look at <kbd>**[`.add_suffix()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html#pandas-dataframe-add-suffix)**</kbd> method:

```py
df = df.add_suffix("_x")
```

Comment: Thanks! Will remember "suffix"-command